# Div padding/background-color not working in outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

```
<div align="center" style="background:#bfcfe4;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" style="font-size: 13px;"><br /><div style="width:666px; background-color:#ffffff; margin:10px auto 40px; padding:10px 34px 34px;"><table width="670" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color:#000000;"><tr><td>some html here...</td></tr></table></div></div>
```

[image]

The top picture is from browser(s) and the bottom one is from outlook. As you can see that the padding in the bottom one is not working. I am not sure why is this happening, please help.

Comment: This template was pre-made and it is applied over 200 times on a site and all the 200 email templates need to be edited manually so this will be something that client would not agree upon. Is there any chance that this can be fixed for outlook ? All the browsers including IE show the email as required but outlook alone is having this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few wacky things going on in your code. It's probably one of these 3 issues:

- the margin (you should avoid margin in email as there is spotty support)
- the missing 4th value to your padding (Outlook may be treating it as 0, causing no padding on the left side)
- your widths don't add up. The div should be the width of your table + left padding + right padding.

You would also be better served to use nested tables than the div as they cause a lot less headaches.

Comment: Thanks for the astute observation of the code. I removed margins and added nested tables and it solved all the issues.

Answer (score 1):

Now used to this **only for outlook**

```
<div style="padding-left:34px;padding-right:34px;padding-top:10px;" bgcolor="#bfcfe4">
```

Comment: Div tag does not have bgcolor as its attribute. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Use style="background-color:#ffffff;" for divs.

Comment: For anyone reading this - div tag does support the CSS 'background-color' but does NOT support 'height' - this slipped me up

Comment: I can verify that the `bgcolor="#bfcfe4"` attribute renders as intended in Outlook.